# How do I retrieve ID3 information from a music file

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

This is what I have so far

```
IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
byte[] byteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
IBuffer byteBuffer = byteArray.AsBuffer();
await stream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, 0, 0);
String result = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byteArray, byteArray.Length - 128, 128);
```

Unfortunately, result always comes out being `"\0\0\0\0\0\0"` with a huge amount of more `\0`'s, it's for every music file it iterates through.

`FileStream` is non-existent in winrt I think, so all the internet's information is slightly off from what I need. Also, there's no stream.Length, only stream.Size, if that makes a difference.  Spent all day trying to figure this out, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this lib ? https://id3.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, had to turn x into an array then assign to a new byte[]

```
    IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[stream.Size];
    IBuffer byteBuffer = byteArray.AsBuffer();
    IBuffer x = await stream.ReadAsync(byteBuffer, (uint)byteArray.Length, 0);
    byte[] newArray = x.ToArray();

    String result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newArray, 0, newArray.Length);
```

Comment: Also see `var result = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();`

Comment: whoa!! this is much easier, thank you so much! I was ready to go parsing all those \0's.